# distance estimation opencv base on vector

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, vector-graphics

I'm trying to calculate distance using OpenCV and by simulating 2d vector field.

short story : 
I have :

- camera angle
- camera position
- 2 object position

[image : 2d field on x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1WJc.png)

I have camera setup at certain height and angle.
my first scene, object at position (3,0) (in frame:y=0). 
second scene, at (5,0) (in frame:y=240)

my question is,

- before continue, is this method could be used?
- how do I know where the object would be in frame, given the object at    (7,0)? what equation should I use?
- do I need aware of lens distortion? (currently using video input, later will be using camera) do camera distortion callibration will
  fix it?

long story :

I need to estimate a car distance.
I have read http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/., it using fixed width or height of an object, means if the object changed, result will be changed (am I right?) so I need to have a workaround method.

Or if you have better method, I will be glad to know it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the camera position and properties, you can find the exact location of the car, if it's looking at a straight road and the cars are not flying:)

> how do I know where the object would be in frame, given the object at
> (7,0)? what equation should I use?

- You need to find the [intersection of two lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection). The first line crossing points *p1(0, 1.5)* and *p2(0,7)*; second line *P1(3,0)*, *P2(f/cos(a), 1.5)*

  P2 is the intersection of green line (image plane, or the one with points of (y=?),.. ) and horizon. *f* is the focal length, *a* is the angle between fov line and the horizon.

> do I need aware of lens distortion? (currently using video input,
> later will be using camera) do camera distortion callibration will fix
> it?

- You should eliminate the lens distortion. Otherwise only the points on the center of the image can be located precisely.

The link you gave uses the size of the rectangle and triangle similarity to find the distance. Also it uses a 2D object, which means he can find the affine transformation easily to refine the result. You don't know the size of all cars i guess, you just need to find the position of the closest wheel of the vehicle. Good luck with that :) Ask google for something like *real time car detection*.

Shadow of the car also would be a problem, i hope you live in north Europe :)

Comment: great, thank you :)
which is the focal length? is it the camera spec (currently using phone camera) or distance between camera and object?

Comment: camera specs, i think.

Comment: I can't get my phone camera specs.. is there any way to calculate/approximate it?

Comment: i am not good at calibration stuff. Try to do a research on something like "computer vision camera calibration"

Comment: I can't find it's focal length.. what do you think about using triangle similarity? [link image](http://imgur.com/a/3wqai)

Comment: consider this, f = height(C,A,h1) = height(C,A,h2). If you know the point h1 or h2; or the angle theta1 or theta2, then you can find the height with some trigonometry.